# Can you say "that which" instead of "that that"?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns, that

Which is better: "...and it is that that is our 'result'" vs "...and it is that which is our 'result'"?

Comment: Could you please provide a context?

Answer (score 1):

With as much context as you've given, that which is preferable. Of course not every that that can be substituted like this, depending on which that is the conjunction and which is the pronoun.